# How to send a null value to a not null column in ASP.NET with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, webforms

my problem is this:

- I have a table in **SQL Server** that have a *NOT NULL Column* that uses a *SEQUENCE* as default (NEXT VALUE FOR SeqDefa),
  that column is not the **PK** from the table.
- I building a web form in **ASP.NET** that does a CRUD in that table, when i want to send a `null` value in that column to use the default in that table i get an error. that's because LINQ says that you can't send a null value to a not null column

how can i fix it?

can i get the sequence´s next value  from LINQ in my form?
there's another option than changing table column from not null to allowing nulls?

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: Linq is not a database technology. Are you using Linq-to-sql or something else?

Comment: Not sure you can do it with LINQ but with Pl/SQL it's `select SequenceName.NEXTVAL from DUAL`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework, then you might be looking for the `[DatabaseGenerated]` attribute or `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` in the fluent API.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=fluent-api)

Answer (score 0):

If You are using EF core, You could also look at [Value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations).
Write a simple one that will set chosen default value when given value is `null`, or some calculated value if You prefer.
Thanks to this You there will be no more need to have some special behaviour in your linq code - just normally use `null` when needed and value converter will take care of the rest.